# Installation of Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: usb-installation

I have downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.1 on my Flash memory. Now I want to make one live Ubuntu on my

Flash memory. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

use **"universal usb installer"(uui)** to create a bootable usb with your iso (you can download uui online)

boot up to live usb and complete installation

i assume you're using windows

Answer (score 0):

Install [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) on your OS. (It's available for windows/linux AFAIK). Now copy the Ubuntu 14.04.1 image (ISO file) to your computer.

Open UnetBootin.

Select your ISO file, Select your thumb drive.

Press next and it will burn the ISO on your thumb drive. Now you can restart the computer with USB inserted into the CPU.

You may need to change the boot device preferences in the BIOS for it to try to boot from your thumb drive first before using the harddisk to boot into the existing OS. You can do that as shown [here](http://www.prime-expert.com/flashboot/setting_up_bios.php).

Answer (score 0):

Search for and install **Startup Disk Creator** from the Ubuntu Software Center.  This is a GUI that will allow you to select your downloaded *.iso file and your USB disk to create a Live USB.

You can also install it from the terminal if you like...

```
sudo apt-get install usb-creator-gtk
```

By the way, before you use your USB with Startup Disk Creator, format it to FAT32 using GParted Partition Editor (gparted, also from the Software Center).  Set the flag to be bootable.

[image]